# generate document and then zip with php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an issue.
I have an index.php with several checkboxes. 
Every checkbox represents a piece of code.
I am trying to create some generating tool.
For example: if I select four checkboxes, I want that four specific parts of code to generate in one php file, then zip it and download on my computer.

[image]

I know I can do it something like this:

```
$files = array('list.php', 'one-image.php', 'gallery.php', 'pdf.php');
$zipname = 'file.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
$zip->addFile($file);
}
$zip->close();

header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
readfile($zipname);
```

but, at the moment i am pretty lost. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't just say "I am pretty lost". Describe your problem. What does your code not do that you want it to do? Or what does it do that you do not want? Don't make us pore over your code to figure out what you meant, or recreate your project on our computers.

Comment: The problem of above code is that it make zip file with four php files, I want just one generated file.

Comment: Read the files yourself using `file_get_contents`, concatenate using `+`, write to zip with `ZipArchive::addFromString`.

Comment: Amadan, that worked. Thank you. So simple... Could you write this as an answer, so I can vote for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copied from comments:

Read the files yourself using `file_get_contents`, concatenate using `+`, write to zip with `ZipArchive::addFromString`.